# get previous rows filtered by column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple table like this

```
Person
    id,order
    1;5
    2;3
    3;1
    4;2
    5;4
```

I need to get previous rows using order column
For example if the id parameter is 5( order = 4) , i need to return the rows id: 2,4,3.
if the id is 2(order = 3) , i need to return the rows id 4,3

Sorry if I am struggling to make me understand

I created this request but I have so trouble to make it work

```
select * 
from Person p
where p.id= (
Select p2.id
from Person p2
where p2.id=1 /*so should return rows [ 5,2,4,3]*/
and p2.order< p2.order 
)
```

Desired output

```
 id,order  
 5;4   
 2;3     
 4;2
 3;1
```

Thank you very much

Comment: @Tim Schmelter PostgresSql. Sorry for forgetting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to select all with an `order` less than the ID-Order:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM Person p
WHERE "order" < (SELECT "order" 
                 FROM Person
                 WHERE ID = 5)
ORDER BY "order" desc
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c62fc/5/0)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much , works great . it was exactly what i needeed

Answer (score 1):

This matches your description:

```
SELECT * FROM Person
    WHERE "order" < 
        (SELECT "order" order FROM Person WHERE id = 5)
```

The subselect is used to retrieve the "order" of the specified row.  In the subselect I performed the subtraction to find the previous value.  That is used in the where clause of the select to get the rows you want.